# ExtJS: Show/Hide other component when focusing on TextArea

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker, textarea, visibility

I have a TextArea and a DatePicker in my UI.  I'm trying to show/hide the DatePicker whenever the TextArea receives focus.  Here's the code snippet:

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.onReady(function () {
     var textArea = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
      width: 200,
      height: 20,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

       listeners: {
         'focus': function() {
            var datePicker = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datepicker')[0];

            if (datePicker.isVisible())
                datePicker.hide();
            else
                datePicker.show();
         }
       }
    });

  var datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.menu.DatePicker', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        itemId: 'datepicker',

        handler: function (dp, date) {
              textArea.setValue ('You selected ' + Ext.Date.format(date, 'M j, Y'));
        }
    });
});
```

Initially, the DatePicker is visible, so the callback code for the 'focus' event executes just fine and hides the DatePicker.  However, when the TextArea receives focus for a second time, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'D[z.parallelBefore]')
calculateChildBoxesext-all.js:15:353261
onLayoutext-all.js:15:356219
layoutext-all.js:15:233311
doLayoutext-all.js:15:316709
showext-all.js:15:310075
focusapp.js:15
fireext-all.js:15:241297
continueFireEventext-all.js:15:159467
fireEventext-all.js:15:159245
onFocusext-all.js:15:756851
callParentext-all.js:15:65228
onFocusext-all.js:15:760411
anonymous
cext-all.js:15:127065
app.js:23
```

I think the error is in the 'focus' function callback, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I'm an ExtJS/Sencha noob.  Any ideas?

Comment: I copied and pasted the code you posted and had no problems...  What browser and which version are you using?

Comment: ahh nevermind.  I was trying it on version 4.0.7 and the code bugged out.  I tried it in 4.2.0 here: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/docs/Ext.button.Button.1/viewer.html, and it worked just fine.  thx.